# How to make an custom content entity can be refered like user in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities

Follow project examples, I have created a content entity, but how can make it can be attached into another entity as a reference field like user in drupal 8?[image]

Comment: Choose content as the reference type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eyal's comment is just the answer, Choose content as the reference type.
[image: How can make a custom entity can be attached into another entity as a reference field like user in drupal 8?]